# Magento Price Filter Problem

Tags: magento-1.7

I am making a Ecommerce site on Magento, and after finishing i found a issue in Price Slider:

If i have a product of $312, and i am selecting min value $10 - $312

The product of this price $312 is not displaying.

Can anybody help in this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a third party extension I suggest looking into the code of that extension under app/code to find this. But as far as I know price slider is not standard Magento feature. You could of course also look into other extensions , search for magento price slider  on Google and you will find serveral (free) extensions.

PS, via system>configuration>developer you could enable template hints to find out what template is rendering the price slider. Via the template you will probably find to block code.